# How to save a future expiration date with correct timezone in Firebase firestore db

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save an attribute to a Firebase document called "expiration". It will be a date set in the future that I will check on the front-end and see if Date.now is later than the expiration date, if it is then I will render a graphic in the UI to depict that it's an "expired" document.

I tried to save it as a string but then I won't be able to leverage the firebase querying capabilities with dates. How do I same this as a date in the future set to Eastern time zone?

```
let splitDate = game.gameDate.split("-").map(Number);
let splitTime = game.gameTimeET.split(" ");
let hours = splitTime[0].split(":").map(Number);
let meridian = splitTime[1];
if (meridian === "PM") {
  hours[0] = hours[0]+16
} 
let dateString = new Date(splitDate[0], splitDate[1]-1, splitDate[2], hours[0], hours[1]).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});

pollDoc.update({
 expires: dateString
});
```

The date is being saved as a string. If I save just the date object before running toLocaleString it saves the date with the incorrect time zone. How do I save it to the EST time zone in the Firebase database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like unix epoch time integers, Cloud Firestore doesn't save timezone information with timestamp objects.  They are always stored in UTC.  If you're seeing a timezone in the console, that's just the timestamp rendered to your local machine's configured timezone.

A timezone represents a point in time for all people on earth.  If you need to interpret that timestamp in order to render a date or time for a UI, you will need to format that on your own.  If you need to handle someone manually entering the timestamp, you will need to convert their concept of timezone to UTC to store it correctly.

If you're working in JavaScript, you might find the library [moment](https://momentjs.com/) helpful.

Comment: Hey Doug, if I have a date and EST time in the future that I need to store in Firebase as UTC, how do I prep it to be stored in Firebase? For example, let's say we have the date 2019-09-05 8:20PM EST. How would this get saved in Firebase as UTC?

Comment: As I mentioned, use moment and its companion library moment timezone.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with just raw Javascript instead of moment?

Comment: Sure, do all the timezone math yourself.  Post a new question if you get stuck with that.

Comment: I'm diein' :)))